# OpenEJB Logger configuration when running tests from TestNG in Intellij IDEA

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-tomee, openejb

I have a problem configuring the logs output when running tests from IntelliJ.

Every change I make does not seem to have an effect.

I run the test using `@Module` annotation via `ApplicationComposer`.

```
    @Listeners(ApplicationComposerListener.class)
    public class TestLogs {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(LogCategory.OPENEJB, TestLogs.class);

        @Module
        @Classes(cdi=true,value = {
        })
        public EjbModule ejbModule() throws Exception {
            EjbModule ejbModule = new EjbModule(new EjbJar());
            System.setProperty("openejb.home", "../../../build/ejbhome");
            System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath.include",".*(my_app).*");
            System.setProperty("ejb.jndi.name.app", getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.setProperty("ejb.jndi.name.module", ejbModule.getModuleId());
            System.setProperty("log4j.category.OpenEJB","off");
            return ejbModule;
        }


        @Test
        public void testLog_LoggingIsOff() {
            LOGGER.info("*********************************************************");
        }
    }
```

When I run the test, the log line with wildcards gets printed in the console, though I set up configuration that should have turned the logs off for OpenEJB category.

---

**EDIT**

**The solution that did work:**

1. Provide the following settings In the VM options on the JDK settings tab in the Debug/Run configuration (and not in the @JvmParams annotation, as it is loaded after the JuliLogStreamFactory)

   ```
   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=path\to\\file.logging.properties
   ```
2. Provide the relevant file handlers in the config file

   ```
   handlers = org.apache.openejb.log.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
   .level = INFO

   org.apache.openejb.log.FileHandler.level = FINE
   org.apache.openejb.log.FileHandler.directory = logs
   org.apache.openejb.log.FileHandler.prefix = my_tests_log.
   org.apache.openejb.log.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = SEVERE
   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

   java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL %4$s [location: %2$s] %5$s%6$s%n
   ```

---

**Not working stuff:**

Ways I tried to turn off the logging:

1. `System.setProperty("log4j.category.OpenEJB","off");`
2. All convolutions of upper/lower case in the previous statement
3. Setting Environment variables in IntelliJ `Run/Debug configurations`
4. Putting the following file `embedded.logging.properties` to `../../../build/ejbhome`:

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger           = fatal,C
   log4j.category.OpenEJB         = off
   log4j.category.OpenEJB.server      = info
   log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup     = info
   log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup.service = warn
   log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup.config = info
   log4j.category.OpenEJB.hsql    = info
   log4j.category.CORBA-Adapter       = info
   log4j.category.Transaction     = warn
   log4j.category.org.apache.activemq = error
   log4j.category.org.apache.geronimo = error
   log4j.category.openjpa         = error

   log4j.appender.C           = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.C.layout        = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
   ```
5. Putting the same file with the name `log4j.embedded.logging.properties` to `../../../build/ejbhome`
6. Putting the same file with the name `jndi.properties` to `../../../build/ejbhome`
7. Putting these 3 files to the module `dir/conf`
8. Setting IntelliJ classpath to the directory above with `Project Structure` -> `Dependencies`

Neither way has any effect on the line output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEJB uses JUL by default and therefore you just need to configure JUL as on any JVM setting java.util.logging.config.file *on the JVM* and using JUL syntax and not log4j one (by default log4j is not in the classpath).

Alternative is to add in app composer properties (@Configuration):

```
openejb.jul.forceReload=true
# custom handler impl
openejb.jul.consoleHandlerClazz = com.company.MyHandler
# then jul properties, see org.apache.openejb.util.JuliLogStreamFactory.OpenEJBLogManager for advanced usage
```

Comment: Thanks! Editing JVM settings did work. I couldn't make the settings work via @Configuration though, because the JuliLogStreamFactory static initialization is loaded before the configuration is loaded to the options.